# Use or don't use 'w' to calculate the distance for a vector 4?

Tags: math, language-agnostic

If you have a vector4 with `x,y,z,w` and you want to calc the distance to another vector4. Are you then supposed to use the `w` into the calculations?

this:

```
float dx = x - v.x;
float dy = y - v.y;
float dz = z - v.z;
Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
```

or:

```
float dx = x - v.x;
float dy = y - v.y;
float dz = z - v.z;
float dw = w - v.w;
Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz + dw*dw);
```

In the later one the meaning of distance becomes quite abstract (to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do factor in the w coordinate. If you think that this is too abstract, think about the calculation that you'd do in one, two, and three dimensions and see if you spot a pattern.

Whenever you add a dimension, you can think of the distance between two points as the hypoteneuse of a right triangle, one leg of which lies in n dimensions and one of which is in the new dimension. Using the Pythagorean Theorem in that case leads to this result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I never had to use Vec4 but I needed to add it to a framework i'm working on. Does the same logic applies for the dot product etc. (other common vec methods). Or in better words, are there any exceptions?

Comment: I don't think there are any exceptions to these rules.